# Jquery: Make the li alternative show

Tags: jquery

The html code:

```
<ul class="tabtitle">
    <li class="tab1">test</li>
    <li class="tab2 tabactive">test2</li> 
    <li class="morelink cdmore"><a href="http://exmaple.com/new.html">more</a></li>
    <li class="morelink ebmore"><a href="http://exmaple.com/new1.html">more</a></li>       
</ul>
```

If the mouse hover on the `tab1` li, then shows `cdmore` li. If the mouse hover on the `tab2` li, then `cdmore` li hide and the `ebmore` li show.

could i get the effect by the following function. `$('li.tab1,li.tab2').hover(function(){}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is it what you want?

```
// hide morelink first 
$('.morelink').hide();

$('.tab1').hover(function(){
    $('.morelink.cdmore').show();
    $('.morelink.ebmore').hide(); 
});

$('.tab2').hover(function(){
    $('.morelink.cdmore').hide();
    $('.morelink.ebmore').show(); 
});
```

Comment: This doesn't hide both on document ready, and it will keep links as is on hover out, but latter might be something he/she wants...

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="tabtitle">
    <li class="tab1">test</li>
    <li class="tab2 tabactive">test2</li> 
    <li class="morelink cdmore" style="display:none;"><a href="http://exmaple.com/new.html">more</a></li>
    <li class="morelink ebmore"><a href="http://exmaple.com/new1.html">more</a></li>       
</ul>

$("#tab1").mouseover(function(){
  $(".cdmore").show();
});

$("#tab2").mouseover(function(){
  $(".cdmore").hide();
  $(".ebmore").show();
});
```

Comment: If you don't hide ebmore on mouseover to tab1, it will show both...if i hover over tab1 then tab2 and back to tab1

Comment: I know, I just did exactly as he asked. Though it doesn't really matter, as it has already been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Check it out here http://jsfiddle.net/CDQ9g/

Below is the jQuery code you can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cdmore, .ebmore').hide();
    $('li.tab1').hover(function(){$('.cdmore').show();}, function(){$('.cdmore').hide();});              
    $('li.tab2').hover(function(){$('.ebmore').show();}, function(){$('.ebmore').hide();});   
});
```

From above, move contents of second functions into first one if you wish to keep links visible on mouseout. Like so...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.cdmore, .ebmore').hide();
    $('li.tab1').hover(function(){$('.ebmore').hide(); $('.cdmore').show();});              
    $('li.tab2').hover(function(){$('.ebmore').show(); $('.cdmore').hide();});   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jQuery + HTML code that you can use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tab1').hover(function() {
        $('.tab1 ul').stop(true, true).slideToggle();
    });
    $('.tab2').hover(function() {
        $('.tab2 ul').stop(true, true).slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>

<ul class="tabtitle">
    <li class="tab1" style="cursor:pointer;">Test 1
        <ul style="display:none;">
            <li class="morelink cdmore"><a href="http://exmaple.com/new.html">More</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <br />
    <li class="tab2 tabactive" style="cursor:pointer;">Test 2
        <ul style="display:none;">
            <li class="morelink ebmore"><a href="http://exmaple.com/new1.html">More 2</a></li>       
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can see this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/fne8Q/

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of variations.  For situations like these, it's may be useful to use .toggle(), it's much more readable to me: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/CDQ9g/2/

```
$('.morelink').hide();

$('.tab1, .tab2').hover(function() {
    $('.cdmore').toggle($(this).hasClass('tab1'));
    $('.ebmore').toggle($(this).hasClass('tab2'));
});
```